# Tagged facebook photo's not showing up in friend's view.

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I had strict privacy settings that prevented anyone's posts from showing up on my timeline. I was just tagged in a few photos that I would like to appear in my Box photos when friends view my profile. I've changed the future posts settings to include friends "can post on my timeline" but it seems too late. I've added one photo as a test in my Timeline Review. However when I "review what others see" as a friend with zero restrictions the photo isn't showing up in my timeline or my box photos. Below is a screenshot of the test photo's settings and my privacy settings. Is there any efficient way to allow people to view these photos?

All "custom" in the below screenshots are friends, except a limited group.

[image]
 
[image]
 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else was able to point out my glaring error.

The setting "When you're tagged in a post, who do you want to add to the audience if they aren't already in it" was only me. I've changed it to friends and now it works.

Thank for reading it.